# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

In my project, this normally worked, it gives an error now and i do not know why.

Comment: `26.3.1` might not exist... But you definitely should not use it also with `26.1.0`...please make all versions of the support libraries match

Comment: You also don't need support v4 at all. Both support design and support v7 include it

Comment: Which one should i use?  cricket_007

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the latest version? You really only need `design:26.1.0` if not

Comment: You can see here, 26.3.1 isn't a version of the library https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: When i changed 26.1.0 I got error like ''All packages are not available to download!'' @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because this version doesn't exist.
Check all the versions [Recent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) and remove some unreleased libraries in your gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.1

It happens because this version **doesn't exist**.
Check all the versions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

Comment: I did 26.1.0 but I got errors like Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.